# Yii2 - DynamicModel validation

Tags: php, forms, dynamic, yii2

I have a form and I want to change my DynamicModel rule validations depedending on the value chosen in a specific select input. I've read [this doc](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation) but I don't understand why my code doesn't work. I've tried the following with no results:

**MyController**

```
private function createFormModel(){
    
    $model = new DynamicModel([
        'indicador',
        'mes'
    ]);
   
    $model->addRule(['indicador'], 'required',['message' => 'This field is required']);
    $model->addRule(['mes'], 'string');
    $model->addRule(
        'mes',
        function ($attribute, $params, $validator) use ($model) {
            if ($model->indicador == 'semana') {
                $model->addError('mes', 'This field is required');
            }
        }
    ); 
    
    return $model;
}
```

**MyView**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>         

<!-- indicador -->  
<div class="form-group">
    <?=  $form->field($model, 'indicador')->widget(Select2::class, [
        'options' => ['id'=>'indicador'],
        'data' => [
            'dia' => 'Actividad por Día',
            'semana' => 'Actividad por Semana',
            'resumen' => 'Resumen de actividad'
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [ 
            'placeholder'=>'Seleccionar indicador',
            'allowClear' => true 
            ],          
    ]); ?>    
</div>
<!-- /.indicador -->               

<!-- mes -->
<div id = "semana" class="form-group hidden">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'mes')->widget(DepDrop::class, [
        'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
        'options' => ['id' => 'mes'],
        'select2Options' => ['pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true]],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'depends' => ['indicador'],
            'placeholder'=>'Seleccionar mes',
            'url' => Url::to(['/campus/subindicador']),
            'loadingText' => 'Cargando ...',
            'initialize' => true,
        ]
    ]);?>  
</div>
<!-- /.mes -->    

<?= Html::submitButton('Aplicar filtros', ['class' => 'btn btn-block btn-default']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: how are you calling it? how is the form being submitted? you have added a `private function createFormModel`, where is your action to which your form is being submitted?, and above all what happens when you submit the form ? saying **I've tried the following with no results** is not enough info

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [when](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-validator#$when-detail) with required validator.

```
$model = new DynamicModel(['indicador', 'mes']);
$model->addRule(['indicador'], 'required', ['message' => 'This field is required']);
$model->addRule(['mes'], 'string');
$model->addRule(['mes'], 'required', ['when' => function ($dModel) {
    return $dModel->indicador == 'semana';
}, 'message' => 'This field is required']);
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried your code but the field "mes" is always required, unconditionally of the input "indicador" value.

Comment: @4aLifeTime i tested the code and it works as expected. Enable Ajax Validation for form.

Comment: Or you can not turn on the ajaxValidation and make client validation condition:

`'whenClient' => 'function(attribute,value){ return $("#inputId").val()==""; }',`

where inputId is html input element id.
described in docs [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#conditional-validation)